# GPS Timestamp with Dronekit-python API

Tags: dronekit-python

I'm currently using the Dronekit-python API with MAVProxy to log attitude from a Pixhawk on an onboard computer running Linux. These measurements need to be integrated with external data for image processing, and I'm hoping to use a GPS timestamp for synchronization.

The time of interest is **time_utc** in MAVLink message #63 (GLOBAL_POSITION_INT_COV), as documented [here](https://pixhawk.ethz.ch/mavlink/), and I was unable to find any GPS timestamp parameter listed in the [DroneKit-Python API Reference](http://python.dronekit.io/automodule.html).

I'd appreciate any suggestions on retrieving the timestamp.

Comment: Are you sure you want GLOBAL_POSITION_INT_COV?  Neither the pixhawk source code nor the Ardupilot/APM code contain a reference to that message.  APM sends GPS time in the SYSTEM_TIME message (https://github.com/diydrones/ardupilot/blob/master/libraries/GCS_MAVLink/GCS_Common.cpp#L965)  I can't tell if Pixhawk does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With dronekit_python, you can set up listeners for different mavlink messages. An approach you could take, then, is to set up a listener either for #63 GLOBAL_POSITION_INT_COV or another mavlink message which has system time.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313892/how-can-i-get-the-gps-time-from-the-pixhawk-on-a-companion-computer) for an example.

There's also [documentation for the different mavlink messages and their contents](https://mavlink.io/en/messages/common.html#messages). According to the documentation, many messages have time since boot, but I believe that some of these are mis-documented. For example, I've seen #33 GLOBAL_POSITION_INT contain gps time, not time since boot. Just make sure you know the message structure and do a sanity check on the messages that you're receiving.